# How to fix "ic_launcher_foreground.xml:1: error: no element found." in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I have been having many problems with Android Studio recently where I will change nothing but errors will start appearing. I opened a project that was working fine yesterday but now I get an error saying

> Android resource compilation failed
>   C:\Users\Joseph\GU\app\src\main\res\drawable-v24\ic_launcher_foreground.xml:1: error: no element found.

I have tried looking at others with similar issues but found nothing to solve the problem.

I also have the error:

> org.gradle.initialization.ReportedException: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

which I have also looked for answers but found nothing that works.

Answer (score 0):

Copy your ic_launcher_foreground.xml file to below folder

```
C:\Users\Joseph\GU\app\src\main\res\drawable
```

It will work
Or else, 
clear gradle cache , clean and rebuild

Comment: How do I clean and rebuild?

Comment: It's in the gradle option in top toolbar.

Comment: Did you copied in your drawable folder

Comment: Remove all the dependencies ,then sync and then place all that dependencies and sync again

Comment: How do I do that? Sorry I'm new to Android Studio

Comment: Create a new project and paste all your code in that. It will take less time

Comment: I have tried to create a new project but I just get errors before even doing anything. I have been having multiple errors with the program without doing anything. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling, occasionally I get it working but then the day after it will be filled with errors again.

Comment: You have mixed up all your build version in and not able to sync. Before reinstalling android studio delete all your  .gradle , .android folder also